# Reverse for 'user-posts' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: python, django

I got this Exception :

> Reverse for 'user-posts' with arguments '('',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['user/(?P[^/]+)(?P\.[a-z0-9]+/?)$', 'user/(?P[^/]+)$']

and I don't know what is the problem

here is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts')
```

and this is my home

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <article class="media content-section">
      <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.image.url }}">
      <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
          <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
          <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
        </div>
        <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
        <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
      </div>
    </article>
```

why do I get this Exception?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a post with an author with an empty name. Your URL pattern only matches non-empty strings.